# Assigning hidden variable in a function within a function

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps-api-3, pass-by-reference, hidden-variables

I have javascript code similar to the following, however when I try to use 'myVar' within foo(), its value is undefined. I've also tried passing the variable into bar() and assigning it directly, but will not pass by reference.

```
function foo() { 
   bar();
   var myVar = document.getElementById('coords').value;
   // myVar should now be (40.7143528, -74.0059731)
   alert(myVar); // returns blank

   var request = {
    location: myVar,
    radius: 500,
    types: [type] //previously defined 
   };

   //Then send a search request to Google...
}

function bar() {
   geocoder.geocode( {'address':address}, function(results, status) {

      document.getElementById('coords').value = results[0].geometry.location;
      // Let's say the location is NYC (40.7143528, -74.0059731)

     alert(document.getElementById('coords').value); //returns the correct value
     // however, this pops up after the pop up in function foo() 

   });
}
```

with the following HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="coords" name="coords"/>
```

The real code is using Google Maps API if that makes a difference:

Comment: When do you call `foo`?

Comment: Also, when I placed debug alerts, it seems as if the creation of 'myVar' occurs before bar() is called.

Comment: foo() is called onClick on a button (before the hidden variable in the HTML)

Comment: When are you trying to access `myVar`?

Comment: Trying to access myVar (or at least the value placed into the hidden variable 'coords') a few lines down in foo()

Comment: Why don't you show us the full definition of `foo`?

Comment: I've included a fuller definition of both foo() and bar() (a lot of it doesn't need to be shown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bar` runs asynchronously because `geocoder` does.  That means that

```
document.getElementById('coords').value = results[0].geometry.location;
```

actually executes *after*

```
var myVar = document.getElementById('coords').value;
```

You can't use ajax this way.  All of your work that relies on `results`/`status` has to be done in the callback.

Comment: Thanks. What I ended up doing was just putting bar() inside foo(), instead of having it as an additional function. I would've liked to have the separate function, but I will likely not need it.

Answer (score 1):

**[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dgELX/)**

Runs fine for me. Make sure when defining your functions to actually use `function` in front of the definition.

```
function foo() { 
 bar();
 var myVar = document.getElementById('coords').value;
}

function bar() {
 document.getElementById('coords').value = 4;
}

foo();
```